# A question about tangent lines

Tags: calculus

Let $f(x)=x^{4}+4x^{3}-16x^{2}+6x-5$. Suppose that the tangent lines to $f$ at $(s,f(s))$ and $(t,f(t))$ are the same, where $s\neq t$. Find $|s-t|$.

I know that the tangent line to $f$ at $(a,f(a))$ is $ y-f(a)=f'(a)(x-a)$.

Comment: Hint: What are $f(s)$ and $f'(s)$ for your given function?

Answer (score 1):

Hint:  Use what you know:  take $f'(x)$.  You know that $f'(s)=f'(t)$ or the slopes don't match.  Then you know that $f(t)-f(s)=f'(t)(t-s)$ because they are on the same line with that slope. Two equations, two unknowns.

Comment: @user72779:  I don't see an equation.

Comment: It is not easy to solve the equations $f'(s)=f'(t)$ and $f(t)-f(s)=f'(t)(t-s)$.

Comment: Then expand that to show the equations to show your progress.  If you [plot it](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+x^4%2B4x^3-16x^2%2B6x) one point is about $x=-4.5$ and the other is about $x=2.5$